# Using a forward slash as a Scanner delimiter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to use a [`Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to get a date from the user in `MM/DD/YYYY` format and using a delimiter `/` to do so, but as soon as the user inputs data the application ceases to continue. It will work how ever if I simply use the standard space delimiter.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.useDelimiter("/");

System.out.print("Birth Date (MM/DD/YYYY) ");
birthMonth = scanner.nextInt();
birthDay = scanner.nextInt();
birthYear = scanner.nextInt();
```

Comment: Does it throw exception?

Comment: If you are using `/` as the delimiter, are you typing `/` after the year?  ;)

Comment: Any reason why you can't just read the birthdate in as a string and use the split method to seperate out the month, day and year?

Comment: I believe the parameter to scanner.useDelimiter() gets interpreted as a regular expression. Try using `scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.quote("/"))` just to be sure?

Answer (score 2):

Your only delimiter is `/` not newline. This means you have to type `/` after the year or add newline as a delimiter.

Try

```
scanner.useDelimiter("[/\n]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to accept slash and new line characters or the prompt will not return the control to the user.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

        public static void main( String[] args ) {

                Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
                scanner.useDelimiter( "[/\n]" );

                System.out.print( "Birth Date (MM/DD/YYYY) " );
                int birthMonth = scanner.nextInt();
                int birthDay = scanner.nextInt();
                int birthYear = scanner.nextInt();
                scanner.close();

                System.out.printf( "Day(%02d), Month(%02d), Year(%04d)%n", birthDay, birthMonth, birthYear );
        }
}
```

Comment: The forward slash doesn't need escaping.